# Integral of the square difference between the Empirical Cumulative Distribution and True Distribution

Tags: integration, statistics, numerical-methods, hypothesis-testing

Having a sample of observations, $x_i, i=1,\ldots,n$, to test the null hypothesis stating that the data follows a specific distribution  $F_0 (x)$, the Cramér-von Mises goodness-of-fit test statistic is:
\begin{equation}\label{e1}
\omega^2_n=n\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left ( {\hat {F}_n(x)} - F_0 (x)\right )^2 \,dF_0(x), 
\end{equation}
where  $\hat {F}_n(.)$ is a step function, the so-called  empirical distribution function, where at an arbitrary point $t\in (-\infty,+\infty)$, ${\hat {F}_n}(t)$ is defined as  the proportion of observed sample less or equal than $t$. In other words, if   we denote the   observed sample, in increasing order  as $x_{1:n}, x_{2:n}, \ldots, x_{n:n}$ then for arbitrary $t \in  (-\infty,+\infty)$:

\begin{equation}
{\hat {F}_n}(t) = \begin{cases}
0   & t < 0\\
\frac{i}{n}  & x_{i:n} \leq t < x_{(i+1):n}, \quad {\text for}\,\  i=1,\ldots, (n-1),\\
1  & t  \geq x_{n:n}.\\
\end{cases} 
\end{equation}
In addition $F_0 (x)$, the so-called the theoretical  distribution function,  is a non-decreasing function, with these properties:

\begin{align*}
&  0 \leq  F_0 (x) \leq 1,   \quad  \forall x \in  (-\infty,+\infty),\\
&\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F_0 (x)  \,dx =1.   
\end{align*}

In statistical literature,  the  quantity  $\omega_n ^{2}$ is calculated   as follows:
\begin{equation}\label{e3}
 \hat{\omega}_n ^{2}=\frac {1}{12n}+\sum _{i=1}^{n}\left[{\frac {2i-1}{2n}}- F_0(x_{i:n})\right]^{2}, 
   \end{equation}
On the other hand, in some literature the statistic \cite{Cramer1928},  known as $L_2-$ distance,
\begin{equation}\label{e4}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left ( {\hat {F}_n(x)} -   F_0(x)\right)^2 \,dx,
 \end{equation}
has been used   as a  goodness-of-fit criteria to test the above mention null hypothesis,   which measures  the discrepancy between the empirical  and theoretical distribution functions.

My question now is how to  calculate  (using  a program probably) $L_2-$ distance, defined above.

For being  specific, consider the following sample of size $n=30$, with mean equal to  ${\bar x}=0.591$. Let  $F_0(x)$ has   the    form
(the so-called exponentially distribution):
\begin{equation}\label{e5}
     {F}_0 (x) = \begin{cases}
               0               & x<0\\
               1- \exp(\lambda x)             & 0<x<+\infty,\\
                               \end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda =\frac{1}{{\bar x}}=\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}=1.69$.

Figure  shows the empirical   and the theoretical distribution functions, ${\hat {F}_n}(.)$ and  ${F}_0 (.)$, for which  we are interested to  calculate $L_2-$ distance.

```
   [1] 0.221 0.264 0.404 0.009 0.228 0.012 3.201 0.629 0.481 0.909 
   [11] 0.113 0.223  0.626 0.199 0.044 0.861 2.692 0.944 0.182 0.587
   [21] 0.570 0.214 0.729 0.282  0.615 0.366 0.489 1.401 0.126 0.109
```

(If I find the answer for this special case, I could then  generalize  it to other distributions like lognormal, Pareto, and even more complicated distributions).

[Discrepancy between the empirical  and the theoretical distribution functions for a random sample from the exponential diatribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bvKJ.jpg)

Comment: Generalising may be hard: $\int F_0(x) \,dx$ and $\int F_0(x)^2 \,dx$ are not difficult for an exponential distribution, but could be much harder for other distributions.  One approach might be to sort the sample data, then do the integration over $n+1$ pieces.  Note that basing parameters of the theoretical distribution on statistics of the sample data may substantially reduce the apparent distance

Comment: Dear @Henry many thnaks. Does this integration formula seems ok? sum{[c(1:n)/n-(1-exp(-(1/mean(x))*sort(x))]^2}* (max(x)-min(x))/(n-1), where n is size of the observes sample x. The above formula is based on the composite trapezoidal rule, explaind here [link] (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration). Any suggestion for using other methods, please?

Comment: I cannot read your formula, but there should be $n+1$ pieces

Comment: @Henry If one wishes to use let say composite-trapezoidal rule to approximate above improper integral on desired interval [0,\infinity] using the observed sample x1,x2,..,xn. The last sub-interval  is [max(xi),\infinity] and the contribution of this piece to whole approximation has the length of this sub-interval  as the multiplier. The point is that this length is infinity which causes the result of the integral approximation to be infinity. How to deal with this problem, please?